# Can AWS DirectConnect be deployed between Branch office (Remote Location) and AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-direct-connect

My company have few branch offices and have reliable internet connection and have a static IP. Branch office have only one Windows computer. Is it possible to deploy AWS DirectConnect/PartnerConnect between my branch office and AWS? I know we can do this in DataCenter. But not sure about small office with One windows computer.

Comment: You should probably contact a direct connect partner and explain in detail what your setup looks like and wether or not it fits their offerings and what the pricing will be.

Comment: What goal are you actually wanting to achieve. That is, _why_ would you want such a connection?

Comment: Can you tell us more about your use of the connection? For example, in a comment below you mention "my application is a latency sensitive (in seconds)". Are you using a fat client that is connecting to a centralized database? Or is this a web app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible, however setting up DirectConnect is very expensive, and also takes a few months to be installed, for a single machine I'd say it's not worth it.

I'd suggest to consider [AWS Site-to-Site VPN](https://aws.amazon.com/vpn/site-to-site-vpn/) instead, which is much cheaper and easier to set-up. It provides a throughput of up to 1.25 Gbps/140K packets per second per tunnel.

Please check out this [blog post](https://medium.com/@datapath_io/aws-direct-connect-vs-vpn-vs-direct-connect-gateway-97900cdf7d04) which explains further the differences between the two.

If recurring cost, installation cost and waiting time is absolutely not an issue for you then of course go for DirectConnect. Here's [official AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/directconnect/latest/UserGuide/getting_started.html) on how to set it up, however it's not trivial so the best way is to have AWS support guiding you through the process

Comment: Hi Yayotrón, Thank you and good to hear it can support office/co-locations (Branch office). Blog link is useful. My client have no issues on costing. They prefer Partner Connect as well. But I am not sure what are the things to be installed/configured in branch location? e.g. Need to buy any devices or just configure using existing windows machine etc.,? This is what I don't know. Couldn't find any documentation.

Comment: If recurring cost, installation cost and waiting time is absolutely not an issue for you then of course go for DirectConnect. Here's official AWS documentation on how to set it up https://docs.aws.amazon.com/directconnect/latest/UserGuide/getting_started.html, however it's not trivial so the best way is to have AWS support guiding you through the process (added this comment to the answer)

Comment: I agree. Documentation is not clear. Probably I have to give it a try. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Frankly, it's not worthwhile.

Direct Connect involves putting a fiber connection between your location and an AWS data center. The benefits would not be sufficient for a single computer.

Direct Connect is normally used to connect on-premises data centers to AWS.

Comment: Hi John, My branch is an Individual depot where we need to process GB/TBs of data everyday. My Head office and Branch offices located in different location and not connected. So I am planning to develop a solution where I want to send data directly from that depot to AWS via reliable connection.

Comment: You said that the branch offices already have a reliable Internet connection. So, you should be able to send the data to Amazon S3 (or elsewhere) via the existing connection. Or is it not suitable?

Comment: Two Issues: Using internet is unreliable. 2nd thing is my application is a latency sensitive (in seconds). So using partner connect (DirectConnect) would be most preferred way. But I am wondering what are the things to be installed/configured at Depot to accept Direct/Partner connection connectivity.

Comment: You would need a fiber link to a [Direct Connect Partner](https://aws.amazon.com/directconnect/partners), which is a recurring cost. This connects to a router that allows the whole network to connect to AWS.

Comment: Thanks John. With this possibilities, I will initiate conversation with DirectConnectPartner

Answer (score 0):

I would look into using a NaaS provider like [PacketFabric](https://packetfabric.com/cloud-connectivity), [Megaport](https://www.megaport.com/services/cloud-connectivity), or even I think [Equinix](https://www.equinix.com/interconnection-services/equinix-fabric) has a solution to connect your on-premise to AWS.

It depends on what you are looking for but if you need a private, secure, and low-latency connection between AWS and your on-prem, go with a NaaS solution.